# Не работает анимация в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть анимация прыжка для моего персонажа, я её перетащил в аниматор и поставил ей включение по булевой переменной.

```
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))

    for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
    {
        if(animations[i] != "Jump")
        {
            anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
        }
    }
}
```

{[image: Аниматор]

Анимация у меня по какой то причине не работает. Вот весь код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public Animator anim;
    public string[] animations = { "Jump", "Walk", "Walk Backward", "Walk Right", "Walk Left"};

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                if (animations[i] != "Walk")
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], false); 
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
                }
            }            
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                if (animations[i] != "Walk Right")
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
                }
            }

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                if (animations[i] != "Walk Left")
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
                }
            }

        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                if (animations[i] != "Walk Backward")
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
                }
            }

        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                if(animations[i] != "Jump")
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
                }
                else
                {
                    anim.SetBool(animations[i], true);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animations.Length; i++)
            {
                anim.SetBool(animations[i], false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Если дал недостаточно информации, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: нереальное извращенство с этими циклами. зачем тебе массив строк для этого, непонятно. вот есть события `Input.GetKeyDown()` и `Input.GetKeyUp()`, в чем проблема там включать и выключать булевую переменную? может скорость движения еще будем поштучно заносить в массив и в цикле увеличивать скорость `speeed = speeds[i]`

Comment: и еще вопрос проставил ли ты свои булевые в аниматоре и на переходах анимаций

Comment: циклы нужны чтобы не выключать анимации вручную - я раньше делал так anim.SetBool("1", false); anim.SetBool("2", false);, anim.SetBool("3", false);, anim.SetBool("4", false); anim.SetBool("5", true);, и тд. с циклами быстрее.

Comment: я не знаю где ты такую чушь нашел, но ты можешь управлять своими анимация не только через булевую переменную. ты можешь это сделать через float поле, что является намного правильным способ, чем есть у тебя. мне просто инетресно, где ты такую херню откапал. это настолько дико, что даже у Дударя встанут волосы. в интернетах столько примеров, как можно сделать нормально, но почему-то ты сделал самым непредсказуемым способом.

Comment: если у тебя правильная архитектура приложения, то у тебя не будет проблем с анимациями. одного поля speed у персонажа и одной стрчоки кода на установку значения float переменной будет достаточно, чтобы сделать анимацию бега